# PHP How to find inches in string and replace , with dot

Tags: php, string, replace

I have string in PHP like this:

```
$string = 'Monitor Asus VH228D LED, **21,5"**, 16:9, 1920x1080, 250 cd/m2; VS228H, **21,5"**, Wide format 16:9, 1920x1080, VS229H, **21.5 "**, Vf3349H, **21,5 "**, 1920x1080, 250 cd/m2, Asus VH2q8D LED, **21,5 inches**';
```

I need to find inches in string and if number of inches is incorrect (21,5", 21,5 ", 21.5 ") to change with correct value 21,5" -> 21.5", 21,5 " -> 21.5", 21.5 " -> 21.5" , 21.5inches -> 21.5".

The final result must be:

```
$final_string = 'Monitor Asus VH228D LED, **21.5"**, 16:9, 1920x1080, 250 cd/m2; VS228H, **21.5"**, Wide format 16:9, 1920x1080, VS229H, **21.5"**, Vf3349H, **21.5"**, 1920x1080, 250 cd/m2, Asus VH2q8D LED, **21.5"**';
```

How to do that?

Comment: That's great, but, what have you tried?

Comment: I import excel file in php and need to change this automaticaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure you cover all the different possibilities you highlighted above, use

`preg_replace('/(\d+)(,|.)(\d+) *"/i', '$1.$3"',$string);`

(I do not believe mossfoot's answer covered the case of a space between the number and the ")

Comment: What if I have this 21.5'' with two apostrophes

Comment: Short answer: take away the " in the regular expression, and it will match any number with a decimal.  
Long answer: replace " in the regular expression with ("|'') meaning match " OR ''.  
result: preg_replace('/(\d+)[,.](\d+) *("|\'\'|inches)/i', '$1.$2"',$string); (Note: ' must be escaped inside a php string)

Answer (score 0):

```
$final_string = preg_replace('/(\d+),(\d+")/', '$1.$2', $string);
```

Read about regular expressions. A good place to start is http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: This change only first and second number. Third is with space between number and "